# Access to member of abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class BaseClass : IBaseInterface
{

    public int PropertyA{
        get
        {
            return this.propertyA;
        }

        set
        {
            this.propertyA = value;
            // ... some additional processing ...
        }
    }
}

DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
    // some other fields
}

public class ContainingClassC
{
    public IBaseInterface BaseInterfaceObjectD
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now, in order to access PropertyA of a DerivedClassB-Object (inherited from BaseClass), I have to cast the object to BaseClassA's ancestor, like so:

```
// This ContainingClassC is returned from a static, enum-like class:
// containingObject.PropertyA is DerivedClassB by default.
ContainingClassC containingObject = new ContainingClassC();

((IBaseInterface)containingObject.BaseInterfaceObjectD).PropertyA = 42;
```

Is there a way I can restructure these classes to do away with the cast? This code is part of a library, and my colleague wants me to get rid of the cast.

The goal is to simply write `containingObject.BaseInterfaceObjectD.PropertyA = 42`.

Comment: Your description and the code don't agree on much. Please bring one in line with the other.

Comment: Sorry about that... working on it.

Comment: `((IBaseInterface)containingObject.BaseInterfaceObjectD)` That is already the interface type. Why are you casting?

Comment: There is no need to cast - you can simply remove it.

Comment: Assuming that there is some reason for this question could you quote the error message you get if you don't do the cast?

Comment: I don't get an error message per se. The PropertyA property just doesn't show up in IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the line `((IBaseInterface)containingObject.BaseInterfaceObjectD).PropertyA = 42;` you are casting the member to the same type that it is declared in, so the casting doesn't actually do anything.

To be able to access the PropertyA in the derived class - since you are casting it to an interface - the property must be declared in the interface and then implemented in the BaseClass.

```
public interface IBaseInterface{
  int PropertyA{get;set;}
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IBaseInterface{
  public int PropertyA{
    get{ return this.propertyA;}
    set {this.propertyA = value;}
   }
}
```

As long as the interface is implemented properly, ProprtyA should be available in the base class, the derived class or with either of them cast'ed to the interface type.

If it's just a problem of the property not showing up in IntelliSense, then it might be a problem with your settings. Check out Options->Text Editor->C# and make sure you have IntelliSense turned on and not set to hiding anythig.

Comment: As simple as it may be, this is probably what the issue is. The given implementation shouldn't require any sort of casting, therefore, if the OP is having to cast to the concrete type then this is probably the reason why.